# Is it possible to make a div in a container flexible, so that if another element's height changes, the first div's height changes accordingly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am completely new to CSS and have a general question.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="resizable-element">
  </div>
  <div class="flexible-element">
  </div>
</div>
```

"resizable-element" can be resized after the view renders. I knew how to make my "flexible-element" change its height using JS, but I wonder if it is possible to do that using only CSS?

Comment: Probably flexbox, but it really depends on what your requirements are. Have you tried any CSS yet? More info on CSS flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

You add in your css code:

```
      .container {
                  display: flex;

                }
```

That means your two divs inside will have the same heigh size

Comment: If you add an heigh size to "resizeable" then the second div will have the same heigh and "container" will have also the same heigh like "resizeable". That will work, to change my mind give me an codepan or fiddle example...

Comment: Chapeau bas my friend. You are right, suprising as I really had no idea flex also works this way... not very often used it in column layout, maybe that's why

Comment: yea no problem, i also dont use it often but i know what it do

Comment: And can I use flex in those cases when I can close and open my "resizable-element" with the button click? Can flex detect the change of the element height from 0 to '200px' for example?

Comment: if you change your heigh of your resizeable element, your second div will always be the same heigh, css usually detect it, you could do it with jQuery with the "toggleclass" function to add an class with your high